# What is the purpose of the web site of the router's back panel?

Tags: networking, router

On the back of my router-box there is a domain-name of a web-site. This domain-name/web-site is the one of the vendor of my router.
There are also a credentials - user-name and password - to enter/log-in into the admin-panel of my router.

for Netgear router http://www.routerlogin.net user-name: admin-password: password

In which cases should one make use of this way to remote log-in to the router besides that there is already another method for remote router-log-in - by enabling remote access on the router locally and creating ddns in advance?

Comment: it's an instruction of "How do I use the NETGEAR web interface to set up my Nighthawk router?" 
https://kb.netgear.com/22697/How-do-I-install-my-NETGEAR-router-using-the-router-web-interface

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use that link if you have another way to access the router.
(Many routers don't even have this at all.)

It is just a handy way for a novice user that has no clue about networking to be able to get into the router if needed.

Any client that connects to the LAN and tries to open that webpage will be redirected (by the router itself) to its own management web-site.
But if you can find out the ip-address of the router on your own (e.g. look at what default gateway you got from DHCP) there is nothing keeping you from using that ip-address directly.

I have encountered some routers in which the manufacturer really messed this up.
The redirect would allways redirect you to the routers DEFAULT ip-address on the LAN side (192.168.1.1), even if you had yourself changed that address to something else.
I found out when I had reconfigured a router to 192.168.10.1 for someone and he later complained he couldn't login to the router.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to go to the site http://www.routerlogin.net/ that you mentioned, I get the follwing message:

"You may not be connected to your Router’s WiFi network. To access routerlogin.com, your device must be connected to your Router’s WiFi network. Check your current connection and try again." This message has also a link to the following page: https://kb.netgear.com/27199/I-m-having-trouble-accessing-my-NETGEAR-router-what-do-I-do

So I guess when you connect from inside your network, your router is just intercepting requests to that domain name and substitute it's own login page in reply.